# Jersey produces unexpected default media type when throwing WebApplicationException

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am developing a web service using the JAX-RS API with Jersey 1.17 as my implementation.

I want clients to have the choice between JSON and XML which they specify using the `Accept` HTTP header. I want JSON to be the default when a client does not include the `Accept` header in the request. I have tried to achieve this by placing `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` before `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` in the `Produces` annotation.

This seems to work in normal situations:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/webservice/Bob'
{"text":"Hello, Bob"}

$ curl -H'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/webservice/Bob'
{"text":"Hello, Bob"}

$ curl -H'Accept: application/xml' 'http://localhost:8080/webservice/Bob'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Greeting text="Hello, Bob"/>
```

But if I throw a `WebApplicationException` from the constructor of my resource class, the response media type defaults to XML:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/webservice/Vader'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Error message="Illegal name"/>
```

If the client includes the `Accept` header the media type is correct:

```
$ curl -H'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/webservice/Vader'
{"message":"Illegal name"}
```

How can I configure Jersey to use the default even for errors that are thrown from the resource class constructor?

Here is the code of my resource class ([full example on GitHub](https://github.com/glerup/jersey-error-handling-sample-app)):

```
package org.example.errorhandling;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.example.errorhandling.repr.Error;
import org.example.errorhandling.repr.Greeting;

@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("/{name}")
public class Greeter {
    private final String name;

    public Greeter(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        if ("Vader".equals(name)) {
            Error error = new Error();
            error.message = "Illegal name";
            Response errorResponse = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(error).build();
            throw new WebApplicationException(errorResponse);
        } else {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    @GET
    public Response greet() {
        Greeting greeting = new Greeting();
        greeting.text = "Hello, " + name;
        return Response.ok(greeting).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the Constructor and not the `greet` method to receive the `@PathParam("name")`?

Comment: @LutzHorn In my real webservice I capture the `@PathParam("name")` in the constructor in order to expose a handful of subresources. In my constructor I look up the object identified by `name` in a backend system and I want to throw an exception immediately if the lookup fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a workaround due to a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877409/jersey-produces-unexpected-default-media-type-when-throwing-webapplicationexcept#comment33226533_21919071) from [usul_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2635643/usul).

The workaround is to use the `selectVariant()` mechanism to programmatically choose a media type that matches the `Accept` header in the request. This makes it possible to enforce the default media type at the cost of repeating the preferred order.

Here is the constructor modified to use this technique ([full code on GitHub](https://github.com/glerup/jersey-error-handling-sample-app/tree/experiment/select-variant)):

```
public Greeter(@PathParam("name") String name, @Context Request request) {
    if ("Vader".equals(name)) {
        Error error = new Error();
        error.message = "Illegal name";
        List<Variant> variants = Variant.mediaTypes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).add().build();
        Variant variant = request.selectVariant(variants);
        Response errorResponse = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(error).variant(variant).build();
        throw new WebApplicationException(errorResponse);
    } else {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Jersey Exception Mappers ?
Here is an example https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/exception-mapping/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/exception/Exceptions.java

Comment: I just tried to use an exception mapper ([code on GitHub](https://github.com/glerup/jersey-error-handling-sample-app/tree/experiment/error-mapping)). But the behavior is the same, the media type order for the resource seems to be ignored.

Comment: With this, you have a response and so you can set the response type

Comment: Do you mean that I should declare `@HeaderParam("Accept")` and try to interpret the `Accept` header myself? That sounds like a hack. The JAX-RS implementation should do this for me.

Comment: No, I mean you could add .type("application/json") in your Response build

Comment: Sorry, I think I've not well understand. Perhaps Request.selectVariant  is better for you

Comment: I tried using `selectVariant()` ([code on GitHub](https://github.com/glerup/jersey-error-handling-sample-app/tree/experiment/select-variant)) and it seems to be a working workaround for this problem. Thanks!