# YARN Rest API: XML as default

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way to change the default response format for GET requests like `/ws/v1/cluster/info` to be XML?

I know that I can specify the `Accept: application/xml`header with my request. However I want to change the default value so that I can omit the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading of the [Yarn source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/tree/trunk/hadoop-yarn-project), the distinction between JSON and XML is completely delegated to the underlying JAX-RS infrastructure, with annotations like

```
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
```

all over the code. This mechanism (called "Static Content Negotiation") specifies that the **first** in the list is the default, which is consistent with behavior. One could use the `javax.ws.rs.core.Variant` class (and a technique called "Runtime Content Negotiation") to override this, but I can't find any use of it in the codebase.

If you're willing to make a small modification to the source and rebuild it, you could simply find all of these @Produces declarations and swap the order. If you decide to do this, you'll want to be mindful of the apparent bug described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877409/jersey-produces-unexpected-default-media-type-when-throwing-webapplicationexcept). If it turns out to still be relevant (and it *was* recent), you may find you have to tackle all the complexity of runtime content negotiation anyway.

It should be simple enough to try it out, but if you don't have any other reason to build from sources it's probably overkill.